# Stop or pause http 301/302 redirects on browser for development

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, microsoft-edge

As a developer, I would like to **stop or pause the http redirects on the browser**, so I can see the fallback message or just perform some common developments checks. Is it possible? Perhaps a extension (couldn't find in Google) or maybe some "hack" on the Developer Tools. Can be any browser like Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc. in any OS.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop the browser from completing HTTP redirects for websites that you are visiting? Or do you want to have stop/pause HTTP redirects in a website you are making?

Comment: Both options. Can be local sites I am developing (wich sounds easier because I have control over the backend logic) or the ones I visit, like my production sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to add breakpoints in http redirects. You could find out the http redirects in Fiddler and add breakpoints before request or after response. Then replay the request to check it.

[image]

For more information about adding breakpoints in Fiddler, you could refer to [this article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/breakpoints-in-fiddler).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!
Any alternatives for MacOS or Linux?

Comment: Fiddler Beta for Linux: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere

Comment: Although Fiddler may be a solution, it is a complex application that have to be installed in the OS. I am still looking for a more elegant solution, preferably within the browser.